# Two-stages class AB amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, class-ab

I'm studying the following two-stages class AB amplifier:

[image]

Basically it is a standard two-stages op-amp (i.e. the cascade of a differential pair with active current mirror followed by an inverter with active load) to which the source follower M8-M9 has been added in order to provide the single-ended output signal of the differential pair to the gates of both M5 and M6.
I have doubts about some sentences of my book.

**1st question**

The book says that the gain of the second stage (i.e. the inverter with active load given by M5-M6) is:

[image]

Shouldn't the gain be negative? M5 and M6 give raise indeed to an inverter.

**2nd question**

I think that the book has an error: the gate of M1 should be in-, while the gate of M2 should be in+.

**3rd question**

Since the book does not provide the expression of the total low frequency gain, I surmise that it is given by the product of the gains of the three stages. Is it correct to assume the gain of the source follower equal to 1 for semplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q2: when voltage at gate M1 is **increased** then the drain current through M1, M3 and M4 **increases** that will pull up (**increases**) the voltage at the gates of M8 and M5. So M5 will conduct **less** current making the output voltage drop (**decrease**).

No need to simulate that :-) but if you want, confirm this by simulation.

So yes you're right, the gate of M1 is the **inverting input**.

Q1: because of that (written above) now the gain becomes positive.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Gain is only a positive number, the input amplitude vs the output amplitude, It does not depend on the phase, if it inverts the signal and doubles its amplitude, it has a gain of 2 and a phase of 180 degrees.

Q2. Without simulating I am only assuming, I would take a guess its described like op amp inputs, Increasing the voltage on In+ increases the output voltage, Increasing the voltage on In- decreases the output voltage.

Q3. Voltage follower gain stages have a voltage gain of 1, so yes valid for low frequencies.

Comment: I frequently see gain written as a signed number, and it's very useful in that form. It is also common for people to say 'gain' when they mean 'abs(gain)'.

Comment: ad 1.) it does not make sense to talk about phase for dc-gain. ad 2), yes it does not do that. ad 3) thats true for gm*rout >> 1